# Problems syncing files from my computer to my nokia Lumia 610

Tags: lumia, sync, zune, transfer

I've connected my Nokia Lumia 610 to my laptop and installed Zune etc. I've dragged the files that I wanted to the phone symbol like I was instructed.

But when I sync my phone for then to transfer its started syncing all of the files on my computer even though I didn't want them to. Also when I disconnect my phone to check if they transferred, they don't show up.

I'm really confused and new to the software. Can anyone help?

Comment: You'll have to go into the Zune software and change the options for how you want things to sync.

Comment: really? Oh, in guessing that's on setting right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is quite an extensive "how to" on syncing music, videos and pictures from Windows Phone 7 with Zune

- PC: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/music/sync-files-with-my-phone
- Mac: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/music/sync-and-get-updates-with-my-mac

Comment: Could you add the most important information from those links into your answer, just in case they go dead one day?